# Cannot see the content of my shared folder from my hosted OS ( $USER already in vboxsf and VM already restarted )

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, shared-folders, adduser

I have a Ubuntu OS running inside a VM made on Virtualbox.

It's some time that I cannot see anymore the content of my shared folder from my Ubuntu OS. I am loading content into the shared folder form the external OS: windows10.

I have configured the shered folder from virutalbox UI like so

[image]

The UI tells me as I try to access the `sf_VirtualBox_cartella_condivisa_VM03`:

"you do not have the permission to view the content of..."

which I understand, because Isee a red cross icon over the folder icon.

[image]

Then I have run

```
tommaso@tommaso-VM3:/media$ sudo adduser $USER vboxsf

[sudo] password for tommaso:
```

but I get

```
The user `tommaso' is already a member of `vboxsf'.
```

I restarted the vm but the problem remains.

Inspecting the content of folder media, I get

```
tommaso@tommaso-VM3:/media$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 lug 31 14:56 ./    
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root   4096 lug 31 14:48 ../    
drwx------   2 root root 4096 lug 31 14:56 sf_VirtualBox_cartella_condivisa_VM03/    
drwxr-x---+  3 root root   4096 nov  8 15:06 tommaso/
```

So I have opened have opened another VM having the shared folder working, and I see that the permissions and user are different

```
tommaso@tommaso-VirtualBox:/media$ ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 giu 24  2021 ./
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root    4096 ago  2  2021 ../
drwxrwx---   1 root vboxsf 12288 nov  1 10:58 sf_VirtualBox_cartella_condivisa/
drwxr-x---+  4 root root    4096 nov  8 15:24 tommaso/
```

So I have tryed to "align" them manually by running:

```
sudo chown root:vboxsf /media/sf_VirtualBox_cartella_condivisa_VM03/

sudo chmod g+rwx /media/sf_VirtualBox_cartella_condivisa_VM03/
```

so that I get

```
tommaso@tommaso-VirtualBox:/media$ ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root    4096 giu 24  2021 ./
drwxr-xr-x  20 root root    4096 ago  2  2021 ../
drwxrwx---   1 root vboxsf 12288 nov  1 10:58 sf_VirtualBox_cartella_condivisa/
drwxr-x---+  4 root root    4096 nov  8 15:24 tommaso/
```

restarted the VM but the problem remains.

And if I try to access the shared folder form my explorer folder UI I get

```
authentication is required to access gvfsd daemon
```

[image]

What could I possibly did wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

### Update the build-essential package

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

### Insert Guest Additions CD Image

In Virtualbox current VM menu, click on **Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image**

### Install Guest Additions CD Image

Mount the Guest Additions CD Image

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media
```

Run the VirtualBox guest addition installer

```
cd /media 
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

restart the VM

```
sudo reboot
```